# Get a camera's frame-buffer in Unity

Tags: unity, frame-buffer, streaming

Is there a way to "record" the display of a camera instead of rendering it on screen?

For example, if I want to stream a camera's frame block to an external application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is also called Render-to-texture, or FBO rendering.

You can check how to do it on Unity here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html